# Looking for a small chargeable mp3 w/ speaker, that has a easy to push button for children

Tags: audio

Hello I am looking to prototype an idea...I am looking for a chargeable electronic device that can be uploaded with 60mins worth of audio through its speaker and no screen.

Think ipod shuffle nano. The device needs to have an easy touch button and similar to iphone headphones...1 button touch plays music, 2 button touches skips to next track, 3 button touches pauses music.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Let me know if I need further information.

Thanks.